# Preventing loading other classes while opening bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a button on which I trigger opening bootstrap modal popup like following:

```
   <a class="btn btn-app btnWatchlist" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="min-width:175px;margin:0;height:67px">
                                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Add to Watchlist
                                </a>
```

The modal popup HTML is like following:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Add to watchlist button is loaded into the DOM after a jQuery post to the server and when the server returns the HTML I simply update users DOM to display this button.

The issue here is that upon doing a jquery post I add a class which basically displays a shifting gear while the search is being performed and now when I press the button the modal is shown, but this "loading" class is loaded as well with on click of on the modal popup.

The code for making the loading class to appear is:

```
 $body = $("body");
    function StartLoading() {
        $(document).on({
            ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); }
        });
    }
    function StopLoading() {
        $(document).on({
            ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
        });
    }
```

Now how can I prevent mixing of these two while pressing the "Add to watchlist" button, so I can only display the modal and remove the loading class after the DOM is loaded??

P.S. So ultimately I don't wanna display the contents of the "loading" class upon clicking on the button to display the popup, just the modal popup itself ..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you could create a variable that keeps track of whether the content of your modal has already been loaded and then wrap the statement `$body.addClass("loading");` inside an `if(modalHasNotBeenLoaded)`?